# How do I assess the performance impacts of a PK/clustering key that is a GUID string stored in an NVARCHAR(36), compared to e.g. an integer?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've inherited a codebase to look after where predominantly the primary, clustering key of choice in any given table is a GUID stored as a dash-notation string in an NVARCHAR(36). This naturally has spread to other tables too via foreign keying, and seems to have become the model for how most new tables are created through replication of the established pattern without any pause to consider if it's sensible.

I've a concern about the performance impact it may have; I can reason that storage of these PK values requires 72 bytes as opposed to 4 for an integer, but I don't know if that translates to a measurable performance impact purely because SQLS is having to compare 18 times more bytes with every equality in every join it does etc

I'd like to know what steps I can take to make an assesment, in the context of Azure SQL, but I'm not looking to go as far as creating an entire clone of the DB, switching datatypes, adjust the code too, then run a set of side-by-side perf tests from end-to-end. It would perhaps be enough if I can concretely say "the top 10 queries our DB spends time doing (as garnered from azure performance insights) would be X% faster if we used PK data type Y rather than current" - but how do I profile that? And after I've taken the measurements, which figures do I look at to work out if it's the choice of PK ? I'm familiar with benchmarking approaches for code, but I don't know anything about making artificial performance tests of SQL queries and discounting the effects of caching etc